# How can I set this Image Source in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, data-binding, xaml

Currently, I have this in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Image Name="LogoImage" />
```

And this in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public ImageSource LogoImageSource { get; set; }

....

var rm = new ResourceManager("Project.Properties.Resources", GetType().Assembly);

var logoBmp = (Bitmap) rm.GetObject("CompanyLogo");
if (logoBmp != null)
{
    var hBitmap = logoBmp.GetHbitmap();
    ImageSource src =
        Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            LogoImageSource = src;
}

var logoBinding = new Binding("LogoImageSource");
logoBinding.Source = this;
LogoImage.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, logoBinding);
```

I do it this way because I like to keep images as embedded resources, so there's not a bunch of random files floating around in the users install dir.

But how can I manage the image binding (the last 3 lines of code) from XAML and not C#?

Or, if anyone has any input on how they manage image resources, please share it with me.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if the image is a resource you should be able to do: <Image Name="LogoImage" Source="Images\Logo.png" />

Comment: so, why would you do it like this when WPF has built-in means to do it for you?  

If you set the compile to "Resource" it will be embeded in the dll or exe, and you can access it directly by setting the Source attribute on the <Image> tag.

Comment: Ok, I had some confusion about embedded resources vs. resources.  Thanks for feedback, I'm just going to accept the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WPF, you need to use the compile action of `Resource`, not `Embedded Resource`.  Then you can access it like you want to.

**EDIT**

If you **have** to use Embedded Resources, you could do it with an `IValueConverter`.  You're basically moving the code into a reusable class, but it would look something like this:

```
public class ImageLoadingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is string)) return null;

        var rm = new ResourceManager("Project.Properties.Resources", GetType().Assembly);

        using (var stream = rm.GetStream((string)value))
        {
            return BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You'd then use it like so:

```
<lcl:ImageLoadingConverter x:Key="imageLoader" />

...

<Image Source="{Binding Source=LogoImage.png, Converter={StaticResource imageLoader}}" />
```

Comment: The whole point of this question is how to use the image with the compile action of Embedded Resource.  So, while its good input, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ok, so I edited it to show you a way of doing it if you require an Embedded Resource (I'm assuming a legacy app that is sharing this resource, as in a pure WPF app, there is no reason to do this).  As pointed out above, both Embedded Resources and Resources are compiled into the assembly, so if you are only trying to avoid a loose file, I would definitely recommend using the Resource build action.